# mbox: Difference between "From_" line and the "From:" and "Date:" email headers

Tags: email

In mbox format, each email begins with a "From_" line that contains an "envelope sender address" and timestamp. For example:

```
From example@example.com Fri Jun 23 02:56:55 2000
```

How is the address and timestamp in the "From_" line different from the address and date in the "From:" and "Date:" email headers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `From_` line contains the details as received by the SMTP daemon.  In particular, the email address is whatever the remote sender provided in the `MAIL FROM` stage of the SMTP session (this may or may not be the same as what is in the message headers - e.g. it may be a mailing list's bounce address, while the header From: is the original sender's address), and the date is the timestamp of the SMTP session.

See [SMTP transport example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol#SMTP_transport_example)

The `From:` and `Date:` headers, however, are in the text of the message.  They are generated by the sender's MUA (e.g. mutt or outlook or whatever) and/or by the sender's MTA (postfix, sendmail, etc) - e.g. an MTA will often be configured to add a `Date:` or `Message-Id:` header if either are missing from the message.